# NSSearchField clear button does not respond to click

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I am trying to clear field `NSSearchField` by clicking on the clear button on the right side.  I am not able to click on it.

Here is a screen recording of what's happening at my end:

[image]

I used the following code found by RND:

```
[[[self.SrcFiled cell] cancelButtonCell] setAction:@selector(clearSearchField:)];
[[[self.SrcFiled cell] cancelButtonCell] setTarget:self];
```

But it is not working; I have no idea how to fix this issue. Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you setting the action/target? It should work without any configuration...

Comment: by default that not responding so i try to use above code. i did not set any method but without setting above code also that not responding

Comment: Jul 2021, This issue still exists!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very strange. I got solution by just change `TextBorderType` rectangle to rounded and this error got fix now i can able to click on clear button of `NSSearchFiled`. and that working smooth as expected.

**Old one in this clear button not responding:**

[image]

**Now with change clear button responding:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, but my border was already set as shown in the accepted answer.

I found that my override of the mouseDown event, was blocking this behaviour.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"SearchField.h mouseDown");
}
```

Comment: Always call `super` with these :)